# How do you get to know the stack space in C++, and can you alter it? (on G++ compiler, Windows 10)

Tags: c++, memory, windows-10, g++, stack-memory

How do you get to know the available stack space for your C++ programs on your computer? Is it OS-specific / compiler-specific / IDE-specific, and can you alter it? (to increase / decrease the available memory space)

Note: I am using a GCC/G++ compiler from a Windows 10 OS.

Comment: It's OS/compiler/IDE specific. It's not part of the C standard.

Comment: It is system specific, it will be totally different for say an arduino then for a high end desktop processor and will vary between operating systems as well (I think solaris even grew stack space dynamically if you where near a page boundary).

Comment: And no you don't have control over it. The heap exists for a reason ;)

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156510/increase-stack-size-on-windows-gcc

Comment: If you feel that you need to do this, the probability that it would be better to change your code is almost indistinguishable from 1.

Comment: This question make it seem like you're having stack issues, possibly by using too large arrays as local variables. Don't do that, and the solution is not to increase the stack size but to use other means of allocations.

Comment: Also for future questions, please ask about the *actual* and *underlying* problem directory instead. Right now this question is too much of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: @PKramer depending on the OS and compiler/linker, the stack size could be set/changed when the binary is built.

Comment: Why does this question require an underlying problem in the first place? Its like replying to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8454248/making-a-custom-kernel) with "don't, Linux already exists".

Comment: @t.niese Thanks, never needed that. So I assumed from code ;)